# How to Program a, "Deathroll" in C#?

Tags: c#, random, console

**Disclaimers:** I have very little programming experience and that which I *do* have has been used to learn the absolute basics of C# so my general understanding of certain terms are limited. *(I will be using any terms or lingo that I've not seen/heard as a learning experience for my future programming en devours. **So speak as if I know what you're talking about.**)*

> Right, so before I ask my question - I'll need to explain what a,
> "Deathroll" even is to begin with. A **Deathroll** or **Deathrolling**
> is an Random Numbers Generation (RNG) game many people who play
> MMORPGs do in order to *"gamble"* with in-game currency.
>
> *The process is very simple*: Two players agree to Deathroll > they place bets on a certain amount of in-game currency > they determine
> who rolls first > the first player rolls from an agreed upon number
> using an input command on a chat box *(i.e /roll 100)* > a number from
> 1 to the agreed upon number is generated *(i.e rolled: 50)* > the
> second player rolls from the number generated *(i.e /roll 50)*
> ***[Each subsequent roll uses the results of the last roll as the top-end.]*** > the first player to roll a (1) loses and the game is
> over.

My goal is to create a basic program that can do this using C# .net where the User and the Console are the players. I've figured that in order to make this feasible I need to be able to accomplish the following:

1. Have the console generate and print a number from 1 to 100.
2. Make it possible for the user to input a line/command/text that generates a new value from the number previously generated by the console.
3. Have the console read the User Generated Value and then generate a new number from that value.
4. Have this process repeat until either the user or the console generates a value of (1).

My main worry is how I would be able to get the console to read a randomly generated number and then have it generate a new number that is less than or equal to the number it rolled from. My limited understanding of how all of this works makes me imagine that I'd need to created an "if" condition for every possible number that could be generated from 100 to 1, but that sounds rather taxing and convoluted for what I'm trying to achieve. If there is a shorter/easier way to make this happen I'm all open to suggestions.

**TLDR;; I am looking for a way to get the computer to read a number and then generate a new one based off the number it read.**

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as Visual Studio Code 2022. Visual Studio is a fully-featured IDE while Visual Studio Code is a code editor on steroids. The latter is updated very frequently and doesn't use years as major version labels - the latest stable version is 1.7 - while the former gets a major release every couple of years or so - the current version is 2022 and the previous version was 2019. If your question is about C# code specifically then it's irrelevant what environment you're using. If the environment is relevant, be sure to specify the correct one.

Comment: You should look at the `Random` class, which is what's generally used for random number generation. Its `Next` method allows you to specify a range, so you can use the last generated value as the upper limit for the current call.

Comment: with Console.ReadKey() you can read what the user inputs and generate a new number with the Random class

Comment: A creative `Do my Homework` question

Comment: If thats what you want to call it @rioV8 im just trynna learn C# as a hobby for right now and figured this was a decent project to start with. Though I dont know what everything does and I figured I could ask here. Anything you can actually provide would be nice.

Comment: that is the purpose of Homework, learn something, if I write the program for you you learn nothing. Read a good book about C#.

Answer (score 1):

If it is assumed that the user has generated a random value of int, lets say its named x,
you can let the application generate a random integer of a value between 0-x (excluding x) using:

```
Random random = new();
int appGeneratedValue = random.Next(x);
```

If x is of string type you first have to parse it so it may become:

```
int appGeneratedValue = random.Next(Int32.Parse(x));
```

Note that you only need to create one Random object for the application, i.e. you dont need to create a new instance of Random for each number generation.

Comment: I suggest to use the aliased type keyword `int`, instead of the type name `Int32`.